# In React, how do I retrieve information from the database after Authentication but before Authorization?

Tags: reactjs

I'm building a React app which is linked to Firebase Auth.  I followed [this](https://www.robinwieruch.de/complete-firebase-authentication-react-tutorial) tutorial to set it up.

So, I now have an app which allows the user to sign in, by doing the following when the Sign-in form is submitted:

```
onSubmit = event => {
    const { email, password } = this.state;

    this.props.firebase
      .doSignInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
      .then(
          this.setState({ ...INITIAL_STATE }),
          this.props.history.push(ROUTES.DASHBOARD)
      )
      .catch(error => {
        this.setState({ error });
      });

  event.preventDefault();
};
```

Dashboard is protected by being wrapped with the Authorization component:

```
const condition = authUser => !!authUser;
export default withAuthorization(condition)(DashboardPage));
```

So, the main App index.js is:

```
const App = () => (
  <Router>
    <Switch>
      <Route exact path='/'  render={(props) => <LandingPage {...props} />}/>
      <Route exact path={ROUTES.LANDING}  render={(props) => <LandingPage {...props} />}/>
      <Route exact path={ROUTES.DASHBOARD}  render={(props) => <Dashboard {...props} />}/>
        ...
    </Switch>
  </Router>
);

export default withAuthentication(App);
```

So, initially the user is shown the Landing Page, which has no Authorization.  After sign-in, the User is redirected to Dashboard, which does require Authorization.

Currently the Authorization is simply "is the User signed in or not?", which is fine. So the User, signs in, and (on success) is then redirected to the Dashboard, where we check that they're signed in and then show the page.

However, I want the Authorization to be more specific.  I have different types of users - let's say Admin and non-Admin.  Only Admins should be able to see the Dashboard page. This information (whether a user is Admin or not) is held in my own database - not in the Firebase Auth database (I can't change this setup).  So, I need to be able to do the following:

- Authenticate the User when they hit "submit" - this creates 'authUser' with just the email address set
- THEN Retrieve the additional information (isAdmin) and add that to authUser
- THEN Redirect to Dashboard

I can't figure out how to slot in the middle step of retrieving the additional info.  If I do it as part of the 'onSubmit' processing (so after the authUser is retrieved but before redirecting and triggering the Authorization), I can't set it in authUser.  If I do it in the Authentication, the Authorization is called before the database call has been made, so it fails.

I think I need some kind of callback, so that I Authenticate the User, and then instead of redirecting from onSubmit I can trigger the redirect only after the data is pulled. So Authentication succeeds > authUser is populated with just email > database call is made and Admin status found > THEN redirect to dashboard.  But I can't redirect from within Authentication because it's not within the Router.

Comment: Upon successful login, meaning inside the `.then` call of your `.doSignInWithEmailAndPassword`, you can make another AJAX call to your other DB to retrieve extra information, when that succeeds, meaninng in its own `.then` call, you can decide where to send the user depending on their type.

Answer (score 1):

You can chain sequential asynchronous calls by nesting them one inside the callack of the previous one (be careful about [callback hell](http://callbackhell.com/) though).

In your `onSubmit` method, you can make an AJAX call to your other database (let's call it `OtherDB`) to retrieve extra information about the successfully logged in user. Right in the callback of this last call, you have this extra information about the user, which you can use to decide where to redirect the user (if at all).

Here is a rough idea about what the code would look like:

```
onSubmit = (event) => {
    const { email, password } = this.state;

    this.props.firebase.doSignInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
    .then(() => {
        OtherDB.whatKindOfUserIsThis(email)
        .then((userType) => {
            if (userType === 'Admin') {
                this.setState({ ...INITIAL_STATE });
                this.props.history.push(ROUTES.DASHBOARD);
            }
            else {
                console.log('Nope');
            }
        })
        .catch(error => {
            this.setState({ error });
        });
    })
    .catch(error => {
        this.setState({ error });
    });

    event.preventDefault();
};
```

This shape of the code should do the trick, obviously, this assumes that you have a reference to your other database in the UI code and it has such a method that responds with information about a given user.

**SUGGESTION:** This may be an incorrect assumption but looking at the code you have now, I noticed that your routes are unprotected, in the sense that, if the user directly enters the Dashboard URL in the browser after a successful login, they will be redirected there regardless of their type, even if you use the code I pasted above. I assume you'll need to add extra protection in the `Authorization` component to not only check if the user is logged in, but also their type.

Comment: Thanks!  Yes, I'll be adding extra protection to the Authorization component, to check user type. At the moment I'm working on retrieving the user type from the database first.

Comment: Ok, this solution doesn't quite do what I need.  I need to have the user type set in authUser so that, when I come to the Authorization component, it can check against authUser.userType. I can set it in Authentication, but I can't redirect from there.  I can only redirect from the onSubmit call, but it can't set authUser values...

Comment: Why can't you set the `authUser` value from there? How do you get this valus inside your Dashboard component? You should be able to do the same in the Login component. If not, how about creating an `AuthProvider` class that centralizes this information so everything in the app has access to it?

Comment: I'm using AuthConsumer to get the values in Dashboard; I'll try doing the same in SignIn. Thanks for your help.